# How do I do a case/switch query with Progress 4GL 9.1D?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm trying to write a query for a Progress 4GL database where there are around 8 different cases for it to account for. Is there an easier way to do this than a massive if/elseif block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9.1D allows you to change the query filter conditions at run time, like so:

```
DEFINE QUERY q-query
       FOR TableName.

QUERY q-query:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH TableName " + 
       "WHERE TableName.fieldname = ""something""").
```

You can build your query string in a variable and substitute that in the QUERY-PREPARE.

```
QUERY q-query:QUERY-PREPARE(chFilterCondition).
```

You can also grab the query's handle like so:

```
hQuery = QUERY q-query:HANDLE.
```

and then use that to set the filter condition:

```
hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH TableName " + 
       "WHERE TableName.fieldname = ""something""").
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is - yes, you can do a CASE.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iVar AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN iVar = 4.

CASE iVar:
    WHEN 1 THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "case no 1" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
    WHEN 2 THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "case no 2" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
    WHEN 3 OR WHEN 6 THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "case no 3" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
    WHEN 5 THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "case no 4" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
    OTHERWISE DO:
        MESSAGE "case no 5" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
END CASE.
```

The long answer might depend on your query. Perhaps an IF/CASE statement isn't what you need but a dynamic query or something else? To answer that you really need to post more information and best of all: code.